Why did Augustine become Christian rather than Jewish?
In his Confessions Augustine goes into detail about why he stopped being a Manichaean, but he doesn't say what his problem with Judaism was.  I assume he did do this in his other writings. So what was Augustine's rationale for accepting Christianity rather than Judaism?

This is a much better question than your previous one.  The problem is that Augustine was influenced by his mom and by St. Ambrose whom he admired highly.  I don't think he did much study of Rabbinic Judaism.  His main foils besides non-orthodox Christian groups and the Manichaeans would probably the pagans rather than Jews.  It would be interesting for an answer to show how much knowledge he had of Judaism.  Maybe asking about Tertullian is better since he was much earlier and wrote a treatise "An Answer to the Jews".

This is an odd question. In a sense, you are asking why someone would convert to the fullest form of a religion, rather than one that has been stripped of some of its beliefs. I suppose this begs the obvious answer "because they don't agree with those beliefs", but the way you ask makes it seem like the default position would be to embrace "Christianity" halfheartedly. In particular, rejecting Judaism but not Christianity would be strange, as Christianity builds on Judaism. (Except when what you are rejecting is the rejection of Christianity.)

@Matthew I'm talking about the post-Christianity version of Judaism

My point remains; the only sensible reason why a post-Jesus person would convert to Judaism over Christianity (indeed, the only reason to remain in Judaism) is because you've rejected Christianity. So... are you asking why Augustine believed Christianity to be viable? If so, why ask about Judaism at all?

God didn't "start a new religion to replace the old one"; Christ was always the plan, from Genesis 3:15. (God being omniscient... from 1:1, but 3:15 is the first mention.) Christianity is the culmination of Judaism. The only sensible way one can accept Judaism but not Christianity is by taking specific exception to Christ.

I will be honest, this question presupposes a lot. Not to dismiss it out of hand, but it really is a non-possibility.
It presupposes Judaism was looking for converts. The missionary impulse of Judaism was waning since AD 135 (3rd Jewish War) and it was basically gone by the lifetime of S Augustine.
It presupposes S Augustine evaluated Judaism, or even Christianity, on a rational basis. If you read further into Confessions, you will see the only conversion which was completely on the sole basis of reason is his dismissal of Manichaeanism for Neo-Platonism. His acceptance of Christianity was centred on a conversion of his heart through the Saints and S Paul's epistle of the Romans.
Finally, it assumes people convert based on rational weighting of every possibility. This is not accurate. S Augustine became a Manichaean through his scandal of reading the Old Testament, coupled with the fact the Diocletian purges of the cult had yet to reach North Africa in force. Conversion is a mix of environment, rationality and (I taking it for granted you are a theist) a response to grace.
In short, because it was not an option to consider.

"It presupposes S Augustine evaluated Judaism, or even Christianity, on a rational basis. " That seems like a hard claim to fully support. Your answer suggests that you have read the Confessions, but then you conclude his selection of Christianity was effectively not-rational. That is, that his conversion may have been driven by a particular spiritual impulse at the moment ("take and read") doesn't rule out that there was any intellectual process surrounding it. Given that Augustine is known for his Christian Platonism, it's unlikely that reason didn't have some role in his conversion.

It wasn't purely rational, he clearly needed more than a syllogism to accept Christianity. While it was S Ambrose's Platonism which moved S Augustine to reject Manichaenism, it was an answer to a problem he intelectually had.
S Augustine's conversion to Christianity was at once a search for truth rationally and an acceptance of what is the good life, both which are only possible with God. It is both, not either or.
PS. 'Take and read' is the apex of a spiritually sensitive moment born in earlier experiences. Those experinces are both S Ambrose's reasoning and his spiritual fatherhood.

I specifically didn't say it was "purely rational" but I was countering the implication from your phrasing that it wasn't rational.

Considering also your previous question, there seems to be a problem here, namely, that you believe Christianity somehow "contradicts" Judaism and/or (based on comments) represents a Brand New Religion.
This is not the case; Christianity is the culmination of God's Plan that was first mentioned in Genesis 3:15 and throughout the Old Testament. The idea that Christianity represents a "switch" of one religion for another is... problematic. It isn't entirely false, as Christ did come to fulfill the Old Covenant (and therefore render unnecessary many of its observances), however it was always the case that this was expected to happen at some point. Thus, it is an error to treat Christianity as some "new thing" with no basis in Judaism.
It's true that men have added their own laws since then. The New Testament records that this has been going on since at least the time of Jesus. It's true, also, that modern Judaism denies that Jesus was the promised Messiah. So, to answer your Question, Augustine did not find the rejection of Jesus more convincing than the claims that Jesus was the Messiah.
It isn't surprising that Augustine would not record any specifics; if he believed in Jesus, his reasons for rejecting the additions to true Judaism would be the same as Jesus own reasons as recorded in the New Testament. If anything, I advise looking into why Augustine believed in Jesus.
